# Calculating moving average with purrr instead sapply

Tags: r, dictionary, sapply, tidyverse, purrr

I'm using sapply to calculate a moving average and what to go for a purrr solution to be type safe but failed.

First try was with 
pmap_dbl but with wrong result - compare ra <> purrr_ra1.

Second try was with 
map_dbl but produced an error.

"Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `purr_ra2` must be length 31 (the number of rows) or one, not 6"

Packages like zoo and RcppRoll with Rolling / Windowed Operations are considering an alignment "left", "right", "center" of the window which is not the case in my situation.

Can anyone help?

```
library(tidyverse)
  df <- tribble(            
    ~Day,   ~val,   ~bw,    ~fw,
    '01-01-2020',   0,  8,  4,
    '02-01-2020',   73.5,   8,  4,
    '03-01-2020',   540,    8,  4,
    '04-01-2020',   0,  8,  4,
    '05-01-2020',   57, 8,  4,
    '06-01-2020',   20, 8,  4,
    '07-01-2020',   690,    8,  4,
    '08-01-2020',   40, 8,  4,
    '09-01-2020',   38, 8,  4,
    '10-01-2020',   60, 8,  4,
    '11-01-2020',   0,  8,  4,
    '12-01-2020',   40, 8,  4,
    '13-01-2020',   40, 8,  4,
    '14-01-2020',   225,    8,  4,
    '15-01-2020',   77, 8,  4,
    '16-01-2020',   0,  8,  4,
    '17-01-2020',   153,    8,  4,
    '18-01-2020',   950,    8,  4,
    '19-01-2020',   124,    8,  4,
    '20-01-2020',   80, 8,  4,
    '21-01-2020',   0,  8,  4,
    '22-01-2020',   80, 8,  4,
    '23-01-2020',   766.5,  8,  4,
    '24-01-2020',   334,    8,  4,
    '25-01-2020',   660,    8,  4,
    '26-01-2020',   120,    8,  4,
    '27-01-2020',   545,    8,  4,
    '28-01-2020',   145,    8,  4,
    '29-01-2020',   38.5,   8,  4,
    '30-01-2020',   20, 8,  4,
    '31-01-2020',   760,    8,  4)
  df <- df %>% mutate(Day = as.Date(Day,"%d-%m-%Y"),
                      fw = as.integer(fw),
                      bw = as.integer(bw))
  df <- df %>% mutate(ra = sapply(seq_along(df$Day), function(x) mean(df$val[df$Day <= df$Day[x] + df$fw[x] & df$Day > df$Day[x] - df$bw[x]])))
  df <- df %>% mutate(purrr_ra1 = pmap_dbl(., function(x,val, Day, fw, bw, ...) mean(val[Day <= Day[x] + fw[x] & Day > Day[x] - bw[x]])))
  # df <- df %>% mutate(purrr_ra2 = map_dbl(., function(x) mean(df$val[df$Day <= df$Day[x] + df$fw[x] & df$Day > df$Day[x] - df$bw[x]])))
```

Comment: you can just replace `sapply` with `map_dbl`

Comment: Thx, I thought I have to be more "tidy" ;-)

Comment: yes we can probably clean it up, but I was not sure what the question really was

Comment: I'm not sure you need `pmap` here, although I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to calculate.  Because you are using only mapping on one value, you can just use map_df. You achieve the same answer with: `df <- df %>% mutate(purrr_ra2 = map_dbl(seq_along(.$Day), ~mean(val[Day <= Day[.x] + fw[.x] & Day > Day[.x] - bw[.x]])))` although I'm not sure that is correct either.

Comment: Business Science has created a package, [tidyquant](https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant), specifically for working time series in a tidy format. Check out this blog post that focus' specifically on [moving averages](http://www.business-science.io/timeseries-analysis/2017/07/23/tidy-timeseries-analysis-pt-2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `rollapply` is applicable -- the width argument may be a list of offset vectors -- one per row or if all the offsets are the same, as in the question, then a one-component list containing a single offset vector which is recycled.

Answer 1 uses a single offset vector and is applicable to situations such as the example in the question where the offsets for each row are the same.

Answer 2 has more generality than needed here but would be useful if the offsets were to vary from row to row.

Answer 3, like the first answer, requires that the offsets be the same for all rows.  It shows that rollapply can be used without the `width=list(...)` feature by padding the input with the appropriate number of NAs on both sides.

```
library(zoo)

# baseline for comparison - from question
ans0 <- sapply(seq_along(df$Day), function(x) {
 mean(df$val[df$Day <= df$Day[x] + df$fw[x] & df$Day > df$Day[x] - df$bw[x]])
})

# 1
ans1 <- rollapply(df$val, list(seq(-7, 4)), mean, partial = TRUE)

# 2
w <- Map(seq, -df$bw + 1, df$fw)
ans2 <- rollapply(df$val, w, mean, partial = TRUE)

# 3
ans3 <- rollapply(c(rep(NA, 7), df$val, rep(NA, 4)), 12, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

identical(ans0, ans1)
## [1] TRUE

identical(ans0, ans2)
## [1] TRUE

identical(ans0, ans3)
## [1] TRUE
```

**Note:** `df` is assumed to be this:

```
df <- structure(list(Day = structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18265, 
18266, 18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 18273, 18274, 
18275, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 18281, 18282, 18283, 
18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292
), class = "Date"), val = c(0, 73.5, 540, 0, 57, 20, 690, 40, 
38, 60, 0, 40, 40, 225, 77, 0, 153, 950, 124, 80, 0, 80, 766.5, 
334, 660, 120, 545, 145, 38.5, 20, 760), bw = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), fw = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("Day", 
"val", "bw", "fw"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

Comment: To be true - I tried zoo and rollapply 3 month ago but failed with the window.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific question, we can take advantage of the constant offsets and use `tidyquant` to get the appropriate lags as columns, then take the averages by row.

```
library(tidyquant)

df$ra2 <- df %>%
  tq_transmute(val, lag.xts, k = -4:7) %>%
  select(-Day) %>%
  rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Assuming that `df` is as presented in the original question. For flexible offsets, I like the approach by @g-grothendieck

Answer (score 0):

To be true - I tried zoo and rollapply 3 month ago but failed with the window.
This is the history and a benchmark.

Your solution is 
the best one!

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(zoo)
  library(microbenchmark)

  # df as in the initial coding       

  # history
  # 1. version with lapply
  calc_ra = function(x, df) {
    begin_date = x - df$bw[df$Day == x]
    end_date = x + df$fw[df$Day == x]
    res <- df %>% filter(Day > begin_date &
                                Day <= end_date) %>%
      summarize(mv = mean(val))
    return(res)
  }
  ra_lapply <- function(df) {
    df <- data.frame(df, ra_lapply = unlist(lapply(df$Day, function(x)
      calc_ra(x, df))))
  }
  # 2. version with zoo 3 month ago
  ra_rollapply1 <- function(df){      
    df <- df %>% mutate(w1 = as.double.difftime(bw - 1 + fw))
    df <- df %>% mutate(ra_rollapply1 = rollapply(val, w1, mean, partial = TRUE))
  }
  # 3. version with sapply
  ra_sapply <- function(df){
    df <-
      df %>% mutate(ra_sapply = sapply(seq_along(df$Day), function(x)
        mean(df$val[df$Day <= df$Day[x] + df$fw[x] &
                      df$Day > df$Day[x] - df$bw[x]])))
  }
  # 4. version from yesterday
  ra_map_dbl <- function(df){
    df <- df %>% mutate(ra_map_dbl = map_dbl(seq_along(df$Day), function(x) mean(df$val[df$Day <= df$Day[x] + df$fw[x] & df$Day > df$Day[x] - df$bw[x]])))
  }
  # 5. version with zoo from yesterday
  ra_rollapply2 <- function(df){
    w <- Map(seq, -df$bw + 1, df$fw)
    df <- df %>% mutate(ra_rollapply2 = rollapply(val, w, mean, partial = TRUE))
  }

  df1 <- ra_lapply(df)
  df2 <- ra_rollapply1(df1)
  df3 <- ra_sapply(df1)
  df4 <- ra_map_dbl(df1)
  df5 <- ra_rollapply2(df1)
  identical(df2$ra_lapply, df2$ra_rollapply1)
  [1] FALSE
  identical(df3$ra_lapply, df3$ra_sapply)
  [1] TRUE
  identical(df4$ra_lapply, df4$ra_map_dbl)
  [1] TRUE
  identical(df5$ra_lapply, df5$ra_rollapply2)
  [1] TRUE

  res <- microbenchmark(
    ra_lapply(df), 
    ra_rollapply1(df),
    ra_sapply(df), 
    ra_map_dbl(df), 
    ra_rollapply2(df), 
    times=1000L)

  print(res)

Unit: milliseconds
              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
     ra_lapply(df) 104.205800 111.077701 119.316653 113.290395 116.749113 287.685832  1000
 ra_rollapply1(df)   4.318322   4.606702   5.140784   4.744533   5.017736  17.593661  1000
     ra_sapply(df)  15.383019  16.301282  17.992554  16.738366  18.629451  83.400164  1000
    ra_map_dbl(df)  15.418707  16.352354  17.965034  16.823075  18.628220 106.660109  1000
 ra_rollapply2(df)   2.629061   2.825758   3.229295   2.926465   3.099371   9.891077  1000
```